# pyttsx compilation error in windows using py2xe

Tags: python, python-2.7, compiler-construction, py2exe

I have written a python application with using **pyttsx** library . its working without any issue from **tt.py** file. I compiled this **tt.py** file using py2exe module. after compilation i tried to run .exe file. then its shows error like given image
[image]

my
setup.py file like this

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
#includes =['drivers','drivers.sapi5'] #this tried. but making error 
sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {}},
    console=['tt.py'],

)
```

i compiled by this command

```
python setup.py py2exe install
```

i am importing following modules in **tt.py**

```
import pyttsx
import pyttsx.drivers.sapi5
import win32com
from time import sleep
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your imports you need to add `import time`

If your problem consist use cx freeze it is like py to exe and use a code like this.

It might also be a good idea to upgrade to python 3.3. This may sort some problems.

This might help it is a article on your error. https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2006-January/004184.html

```
import pyttsx
import pyttsx.drivers.sapi5
import win32com
from time import sleep
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "tt.py",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "your discription",
    executables = [Executable("The file name", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

here's the link to cx freeze http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

Here's the tutorial on how to use it http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried cx_Freeze for a couple of minutes, but when it didn't work out immediately I tried some more with py2exe and got this working:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

py2exe_options = { 'includes': ['pyttsx.drivers.sapi5', 'win32com.gen_py.C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628x0x5x4'],
                   'typelibs': [('{C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628}', 0, 5, 4)] }

setup(console=['tt.py'], options = {'py2exe': py2exe_options})
```

Note though that this requires you to run the same version (v5.4 in my case) on both machines. If you want to circumvent that you probably need to try something [more advanced](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/IncludingTypelibs).